# return array of numbers in range

Tags: c

Given `int start`, `int end`, `int jump` I need to return an array containing numbers in the range `start-->end` with `jump`. For example, for `start=3, end=9, jump=2` I would return `{3,5,7,9}`. With `jump=3` I would return `{3,6,9}`. With `jump=4` I would return `{3,7}`.

This is my code: (`sizeRange` holds the length of the returned array)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int* CreateRange(int start, int end, int jump, int* sizeRange) {
    *sizeRange = 0;
    int* array = malloc(((end-start)/jump + 1) * sizeof(int));
    int iter = start;
    while (iter <= end) {
        array[*sizeRange++] = iter;
        iter += jump;
    }
    return array;
}
```

But I get an ERROR : `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Did you tried to debug your code with a debuger, or at least with `printf`? For the size of your array, you should `floor` the result of you division

Comment: The expression `*sizeRange++` increments the pointer, not the object it points to. Change it to `(*sizeRange)++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator precedence is biting you here with the `*` and `++` operators. `*sizeRange++` means "get value pointed to, then increase the pointer". You want `(*sizeRange)++` instead. Or use a local variable for counting, and store its value at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence between `*` and `++` plays a key role in your case. When you actually intended to do a increment of a value at the address, your OP has just incremented the address itself. Leading to multiple address increments than the one originally contained in `sizeRange`. At this point your code went into territory of undefined behavior for accessing a violated address and eventually throwing a fault.

Change your increment to `(*sizeRange)++` to make the size variable increment happening as expected. Or perhaps you can make things simpler, by allocating the array in the `main()` and use the function to just fill the elements of the array

```
int CreateRange(int start, int end, int jump, int* range) {
    int sizeRange = 0;
    int iter = start;
    while (iter <= end) {
        range[sizeRange++] = iter;
        iter += jump;
    }
    return sizeRange;
}
```

and back in the main, iterate the `range` for the count of `sizeRange` to access the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Precedence of postfix ++ is higher than  *, so you increase the pointer first before dereference and you got undefined predictable value of `*sizeRange++` when you pass to the array.